# Xamarin Forms Collection View wrong updating cells on iOS + scroll to top when set new item source

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have Collection View for first time on Xamarin. It works good on List, that is only once, but when items are updating (Observable collection) collection view goes crazy.

1. Set new ItemsSource when user is scrolling list, makes scroll to top (on old listview it stays where it was scrolled). It is annoying on both platforms. I have fixed it on iOS by setting ItemsUpdatingScrollMode = ItemsUpdatingScrollMode.KeepLastItemInView, but items are still fading when reloading.
2. On iOS data that are displayed and then updated are updated wrong, even if I use observable collection and implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Looks like collection view is caching data and not refresh when it should.

I thought new Xamarin Forms (5.0.0.2083) brings more usefull things but for now it brongs bugs. I will back to classic ListView.

Comment: please post the relevant code